# SwiftでArrayの要素数を監視したい

Tags: ios, swift

別のクラスの配列の要素数が変化した場合にViewControllerで処理を行いたいです。

```
//ViewController
dataSource.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "dataArray", options: .New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if(keyPath == "dataArray"){
        println("変化!")

    }
}
```

この方法ではobserveValueForKeyPath内の処理が呼ばれませんでした。

Comment: 「配列の数」とは、配列の要素数という意味ですか？

Comment: はい、そうです。dataArray.countを指しています。

Comment: タイトルと質問文を編集していただけると、行き違いのない回答を得られると思いますよ。

Answer (score 3):

KVOではなく、Swiftの格納型プロパティのdidSetを使うのはどうでしょうか？

```
import Foundation

protocol CountObserver {
    func didChange(newCount :Int)
}

class ArrayContainer {
    weak var delegate :CountObserver?

    var dataArray = [Int]() {
        didSet {
            if(oldValue.count != dataArray.count){
              delegate?.didChange(dataArray.count)
            }
        }
    }

    func doChange(){
        dataArray.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
    }
}
```

---

SwiftでObjective-CのKVO機構を使い、配列の要素を監視したい場合、

- 監視元のオブジェクトはObjective-Cクラスでなければならない
- 監視対象のプロパティはObjective-CのKVC準拠でなければならない

という2点の問題があり、特に厄介なのが`NSMutableArray`の`count`は監視不可能なプロパティということです。対処法としては手動で通知メソッドを書くか、`mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:`を使うかですが、どちらも表題の要件を簡単に満たすのは難しいです。